# Can I have a class A and class B on same switch?

Tags: networking, switch

Is it possible to have both a class A and a class B network on the same switch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classful networking has been replaced by [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) (Classless Inter-Domain Routing).  So a more generic form of your question is "Is it okay to have two subnets on the same switch?".  The answer to this is in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/25907/what-are-the-implications-of-having-two-subnets-on-the-same-switch) (But the summary is that it is okay).

I recommend you spend some time reading Evan's answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/serverfault-wiki-how-does-subnetting-work), as it is a great overview of subnetting.