# Network: Many subnets in 1 VLAN =? possible

Tags: networking

Is it possible to gather (by a protocol for instance) 2 subnets in 1 VLAN:
example: 172.16.0.0/24 and 172.16.10.0/24 in VLAN ID=20.
Thanks for the information. We are working with Nortel VLAN switch 5530.
Kind regards.

Comment: Kinda like this: http://serverfault.com/questions/25907/what-are-the-implications-of-having-two-subnets-on-the-same-switch

Answer (score 5):

You can run many subnets in a single broadcast domain, yes.

Nodes on the different subnets will see each other's broadcast traffic (ARP, DHCP, etc) but unicast traffic is like ships in the night - the router will just need an address on each subnet within the Vlan to act as gateway for each.

Answer (score 2):

VLANs are a layer 2 function and don't even care IF you're using IP, let alone how you subnet them. So yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have multiple IP subnets on the same Ethernet network? Yes.

A VLAN is a (subset) of an Ethernet network, and behaves exactly like that.

So, yes, you can have multiple IP subnets on the same VLAN.

But if you want them to talk to each other, you'll need something to do the routing: a router, or the same switch which handles the VLANs, if it's layer-3 capable.